# Android date picker showing incorrect format

Tags: java, datetime, java-8

I'm having trouble getting the right format here. I'm trying to get a proper date from my android date picker to shove into a date object.

**My Code**

```
                final android.icu.util.Calendar cldr = android.icu.util.Calendar.getInstance();
            int day = cldr.get(android.icu.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            int month = cldr.get(android.icu.util.Calendar.MONTH);
            int year = cldr.get(android.icu.util.Calendar.YEAR);

            picker = new DatePickerDialog(getContext(),
                    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                            txtDate.setText(dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);
                        }
                    }, year, month, day);
            picker.show();
```

**The result is**
`16-08-21(d-mm-yy)`
but I needed `16-Aug-21 (dd-mmm-yy)`

Can you please help me out on the same ?

Comment: 21? Does the date picker give you 21 for 2021, or did you pick a date in year 21 CE? Both sound very unlikely to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

parse date string to date object and then format to dd-MMM-yy

```
    String dateString = "16-08-21";

    Date parsedDate = SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy").parse(dateString);

    String formattedDateString = SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy").format(parsedDate);

    Log.d("mridx", "onCreate:" +parsedDate);

    Log.d("mridx", "onCreate:" + formattedDateString);
```

logs

D/mridx: onCreate: Mon Aug 16 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2021

D/mridx: onCreate: 16-Aug-21

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. We have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. Yes, you can use it on Android. For older Android look into [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table).

Answer (score 0):

### java.time

You tagged your question java-8, so I suppose you want the Java 8 solution. Use java.time, the modern Java date and time API introduced in Java 8, for your date work.

Unfortunately your date picker uses month numbers 0 through 11 as a remainder from the outdated `Calendar` class. So in our code we need to add 1.

```
    int year = 2021;
    int monthOfYear = Calendar.AUGUST; // Don’t use Calendar in your code; for demonstration only
    int dayOfMonth = 16;
    
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(year, monthOfYear + 1, dayOfMonth);
    String dateString = date.format(DATE_FORMATTER);

    System.out.println(dateString);
```

I have used this static formatter:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_FORMATTER
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yy", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Output from this snippet is:

> 16-Aug-21

### Question: Doesn’t java.time require Android API level 26?

java.time works nicely on both older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On older Android either use desugaring or the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. In the latter case make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table)
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.